# How to write an instead of update trigger correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

Imagine the following example with the table `t` and the view `v`.

```sql
create table t (a int, b int, c int);
insert into t values (1, 2, 3);
create view v as select * from t;
```

Now I want the write an "instead of update" trigger for the view in that way, that all updates of the view will update the table. I know that I do not need it in this simplified example, because PostgreSQL can do it automatically. But in my real world use case it is necessary.

Is this the correct way to implement the update trigger?

```sql
create function u () returns trigger as $$
begin
  update t set a = new.a, b = new.b, c = new.c;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
create trigger t instead of update on v
for each row execute procedure u ();
```

I am not sure, because I am wondering whether there is a difference between the update of the table and the view:

```sql
update t set a = 0 where a = 1;
update v set a = -1 where a = 0;
```

I expect that the update of the table updates only one column. But I fear that the update of the view updates three columns in the table.

Is this the case? And if so how to work around this?

Comment: You could always try both of those and *profile* to see if there's a measurable difference, and then (if it exists) decide if the difference actually matters to you. Bear in mind that the data is stored in a *row*-wise fashion and you'll still be hitting the same rows either way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have no other trigger implementation to compare to. A comparison between the table update and the view update makes no sense, because it is obvious that the view update will be slower, because of the additional function call.

Comment: Because of MVCC an UPDATE in Postgres is a DELETE/INSERT operation so you will get two versions(at least) of that row in either case, until such time as VACUUM cleans up the unneeded rows.

Comment: Well, 1) You could compare table to view and see if there's a *meaningful* difference at all and 2) You can trivially re-write your trigger to only support the `a` column which would give you the second trigger to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any update on a table, no matter how many rows it modifies, will always write the same amount of data. The reason is that an `UPDATE` creates a new version of the complete row.

The `UPDATE` on the view will take longer, because calling a trigger is some overhead.

By the way, you don't need that trigger at all. Simple views like that are automatically updateable, even without a trigger.

Comment: I found it in the documentation of the [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-vacuum.html) command: *"In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table"*.

Comment: Yes, that too, but that is not directly related.